# Can size of a module's port be input as a parameter in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a hardware algorithm that compares two operands, each (keyBits) bits long, and returns a logical one if the first operand is less than the second, and returns a logical zero otherwise. This algorithm works for any integer value of (keyBits) greater than one. So can I write my algorithm with the following Verilog code, by passing (keyBits) in as a parameter? I haven't tried compiling or simulating this code; quite frankly I don't know how to do either. Can anyone help me with that?

````
module lessThan ( lfLessThanRg, left, right);

parameter integer keyBits = 2;
integer maxBit = keyBits - 1;

output lfLessThanRg;
input [maxBit:0] left, right;

wire[maxBit:0] notLeft;
wire[maxBit:1] ltHere, ltEve, ltBelow, equal;

or( lfLessThanRg, ltHere[ maxBit], ltEve[ maxBit]);

genvar integer bit;

generate
  for (bit = maxBit; 0 < bit; bit = bit - 1)
  begin
    and( ltHere[ bit], notLeft[ bit], right[ bit]);
    and( ltEve[ bit], equal[ bit], ltBelow[ bit]);
    or( equal[ bit], notLeft[ bit], right[ bit]);
    not( notLeft[ bit], left[ bit]);
    if (1 < bit)
    begin
      or( ltBelow[ bit], ltHere[ bit - 1], ltEve[ bit - 1]);
    end
  end
endgenerate

and( ltBelow[ 1], notLeft[ 0], right[ 0]);
not( notLeft[ 0], left[ 0]);

endmodule
```
````

Comment: This is one of the main use cases for parameters that I've seen. If you run into problems when compiling your code and can't figure out what's going wrong, feel free to ask a new question. The question of compiling/simulating this code is not a good fit for this site, though, since it is too open-ended. You may run in to problems with the name "bit".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `parameter` to the front of the line declaring `maxBit`. Also remove the `integer` after `genvar`. After that I was able to synthesize and simulate on https://www.edaplayground.com

FYI, I would discourage `bit` as a variable identifier. It is legal for Verilog but it a keyword type for SystemVerilog. All modern Verilog simulators are SystemVerilog simulators. For the most part you can mix the two by keeping the Verilog files as .v and SystemVerilog as .sv, but most simulators have a option to force all .v files to be read as SystemVerilog. There is also an potential issue when you mix the two with `` `include `` statements. To keep your Verilog forward compatible, avoid using SystemVerilog keywords as identifiers (net names, register names, module names, genvar names, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare identifiers used where constant expressions are required as a `parameter` or `localparam`, not a variable. A `localparam` is the same as a `parameter` except it cannot be overwritten.

`maxBit` is being used to declare the width other identifiers, so it needs to be declared as a parameter/localparam.

Here is your example written in Verilog-2001 syntax with all the parameter's, followed by all the ports in the module header.

````
module lessThan
  #(parameter  integer keyBits = 2,
    localparam integer maxBit = keyBits - 1)
  (
    output lfLessThanRg, 
    input [maxBit:0] left, right
  );
  
  wire[maxBit:0] notLeft;
  wire[maxBit:1] ltHere, ltEve, ltBelow, equal;
  or( lfLessThanRg, ltHere[ maxBit], ltEve[ maxBit]);
  genvar  gbit;

  for (gbit = maxBit; 0 < gbit; gbit = gbit - 1)
    begin : each_gbit
      and( ltHere[ gbit], notLeft[ gbit], right[ gbit]);
      and( ltEve[ gbit], equal[ gbit], ltBelow[ gbit]);
      or( equal[ gbit], notLeft[ gbit], right[ gbit]);
      not( notLeft[ gbit], left[ gbit]);
      if (1 < gbit)
        begin : zero_gbit
          or( ltBelow[ gbit], ltHere[ gbit - 1], ltEve[ gbit - 1]);
        end
    end

  and( ltBelow[ 1], notLeft[ 0], right[ 0]);
  not( notLeft[ 0], left[ 0]);

endmodule
```
````